# Default policy for OUTPUT

Tags: linux, iptables

Are there any security risks of having policy for OUTPUT set to ACCEPT?

Machine in question is VPS hosting few websites, git repositories, jabber server and mail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "risk" is that any process on the machine is then allowed to initiate a network connection and send network packets.

That means there is nothing on the server to block any user, legitimate or not, nor any process from potentially trying to connect any other networked device within your own network or possibly the whole internet.

Often that isn't much of a problem, it is considered the responsibility of the remote systems to restrict incoming traffic in the first place and you might have firewall policies already on critical points in your network.

Setting the default policy to anything else, for instance REJECT, means that you will need to explicitly authorise all legitimate traffic flows, which requires a thorough understanding of your system and all applications and dependancies that run on your server. Often that means a considerable administrative burden.

The benefit is of course that the potential impact of misconfigured application is mitigated, it might make it more difficult to abuse a system, although on a thoroughly compromised system the attacker can always simply switch off a software firewall...

From a security perspective it is of course quite simple, anything that isn't explicitly allowed is to be denied. That makes a lot of sense in an environment with strong security requirements and for instance on a dedicated firewall, on a multi-purpose server doing so might be prohibitively difficult.

Comment: Grumble.  Another day, another beautifully-written, textbook-precise HBruijn answer, another +1 from me.

Comment: @MadHatter I wasn't trying to steal your thunder and hopefully you didn't feel the need to abandon your own answer halfway through. Thanks though!

Comment: Oh, by no means.  I read the question, started to compose an answer in my head, scrolled down and saw you'd already written it!

Answer (score 0):

Setting an output policy won't stop break-in attempts, but it might help a bit against malicious, or just clueless, users who can log into the machine. And it might help migitate the effects of an attack, especially a botted one.

For example, you might be in a situation where you have to allow some users on the machine whom you don't really trust - you don't think they're malevolent, but rather incompetent. (Like a customer i had who wanted a separate directory for their 16yo son to host his own website, and who *required* his son to have ssh access. Or your boss who insists you give the new intern ssh access. Or ....). They don't have root access (and they aren't clever enough to use some local-user-gets-root-exploits), so they can't really damage much, but blocking all output traffic at least prevents them from installing TeamViewer or a similar software that opens connections from inside to allow other IPs to connect.

Also, should your server become part of a botnet somehow, dropping outbound packets prevents the bot from sending spam and DDOS attacks from your server. Of course, the damage is already done when the bot installs, but at least you won't pay for the bandwidth. If you *have* to send mail from your server, use a dedicated mailhost and allow port 25 to that host *only*; bots typically won't be clever enough to route their spam through this mailhost as well.

I'd log the output as well as reject it, and check the logs once a week (or once a day, or have a monitoring program check the size increase of the log file, or ... depending on your requirements). This helps you a) find out what you should unblock, in case an application has valid requests that get blocked, and b) find out you've been hacked, if you see lots of dropped connections in your OUTPUT log.